# Who was Tyrion Lannister's champion in Ep. 6?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In episode 6 of [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) season 1 Tyrion requests a trial by combat and asks for a champion.  Some guy that I have no idea who he was volunteered and won.  Who was that and where did he come from?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The champion was [**Bronn**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bronn), he was in the tavern when lady Catelyn abducted him on behalf of all the bannerman and he was a mercenary in those troops.

On the ride to the Eyrie, they have a slight bonding moment and Bronn decides that allying himself with Tyrion would be more profitable due to him being a Lannister, and, I believe in secret, respect Tyrion's attitude towards life.

Comment: would like to point out that Bronn was at the inn, not a mercenary of the troop. He and his fellow were sellswords, who fell in with the troops for rewards. Also, during the journey, the sellsword merely was a companion to the Imp. During his trial, the Imp promised the sellsword wealth should he champion him.

Comment: In the books, they have an interesting conversation about this, where Tyrion said he expected that Bronn brought him to the Eyrie in hopes for a monetary reward, and maybe a stable job.  When the Starks/Arynns didn't give him anything, he backed the Lannister instead, for gold.  Bronn never explicitly confirmed this to my memory though.

Answer (score 6):

It was [Bronn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bronn), a sellsword who took up as the Imp's champion for wealth. He met the Imp when Lady Catelyn was at The Inn at the Crossroads and called forth men to seize Tyrion. He fell in with the other Vale men for rewards, but grew close to the Imp during the journey to Eyrie.